# Stick a secondary form to the main form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a question that I can't find on the net. Is it possible to "stick" a secondary form to the Main Form? My scenario is..

1. I have a main Form that will never be closed and has some button to open other forms..
2. When I open a secondary form, is there a way to "stick" it to the main form? Like, when I move my main form, I want the secondary form to move with it and the secondary form will be ALWAYS in front of the main Form.

I've tried the code below:

```
private void getCalendario()
{
    Calendario calendario = new Calendario(matricola);
    calendario.MdiParent = this;
    calendario.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(calendario_FormClosing);
    calendario.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
    calendario.Show();
    calendario.BringToFront();
}
```

Comment: is main form `IsMdiContainer = true;` ?

Comment: Yes is set to true, but the Secondary forms by the way does not stack on the main Form

Comment: What is your problem? That Calendario is not really MdiChildForm? Because if it was, it would be created inside mainform and thus it would act like you want.

Comment: FYI: If you're using ``` for code, don't post code on the same line as ```, because that line won't be displayed

Comment: You are asking for an "owned window".  It is always on top of its owner and automatically minimizes when the owner is minimized.  You get one by using the Show(owner) overload.  No terribly compatible with the olden MDI windowing model, you'd have to use the MdiParent as the owner

Comment: The problem is that.. all my other Forms are working if i do `.MdiParent = this` or for the subforms `.MdiParent = this.ParentForm` form... but this one doesnt work, this is why im asking...

Comment: You can code the Move and Resize events.